# Mallocing a pointer to another struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm wondering if I have to allocate memory twice in this situation.
For instance:
consider that I have the structs:

```
struct ErrorCheck {
    int returnValue;
    struct Nodes * list;
};

struct Nodes {
    char * name;
    int grade;
    struct Nodes * next;
};
```

And a function that mallocs them:

```
void buildList() {
    struct ErrorCheck * newStruct;
    newStruct = malloc(sizeof(struct ErrorCheck));
    newStruct->list = malloc(sizeof(struct Nodes));

}
```

Do I have to malloc twice as shown above? Or is the first malloc sufficient, if I want to use both structs.

As in is: `newStruct = malloc(sizeof(struct ErrorCheck));` sufficient on it's own, is there a situation where either case can be true or false?

Comment: Let's think about that: you want to access **two** objects. So is allocating **one** object sufficient? I don't think so.

Comment: It is technically possible to only use one malloc, but it is a lot of mucking around and not worth the effort and complication

Comment: Note: after `newStruct->list = malloc(sizeof(struct Nodes));`  newStruct->list->next (and the other members) is/are still unitialized.
`

Comment: Of course, but those get initialized in other functions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That actually depends what you want to do with `list`.

- If you want `list` to act as a standalone variable with it's own memory where you can read from and write to, you'll be needing the second `malloc()`.
- If you want `list` to act like a *placeholder*, for example, assign some other already-allocated pointer to it and then use it, in that case, you don't need the ``malloc().

`malloc()`-ing for `sizeof(struct ErrorCheck)` and storing the pointer into `newStruct` gives you enough memory for the member variable themselves, i.e, it allocates memory for an `int` and an `struct node *` member variable. The memory address, where the pointer point to is indeterminate. You need to allocate memory seperately to the pointer variable to make it point to somewhere meaningful.

That said,

- You should always check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.
- You need to call to `free()` for each allocation *you* do.

Comment: "Do I have to malloc twice as shown above? Or is the first malloc sufficient, **if I want to use both structs**." - Occam's Razor ...

Comment: I definitively want to write to the list, so the former seems to be it;

Comment: @Olaf _use_ is not a very clear statement, so I tried explaining both the scenarios, to avoid any possible confusion. :)

Comment: So my code is fine assuming I free everything at the end?

Comment: @efefefef I've appended my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @efefefef Looks like it, yes.

Comment: @efefefef: It is impossible from the information given to tell the code is _correct_. Just that: `void buildList()` is a deprecated signature. Use prototype-style function declarators: `void buildList(void)`. C is not C++!

Comment: @Olaf `void buildList()` Looks OK for a function definition.  Sure it is deprecated?

Comment: See the standard, 6.11.6p1 (actually "deprecated" is weaker than "obsolecence".)

Comment: @Olaf That is "6.11.6 Function declarators".  Agree about using `void buildList();` yet OP's use is a function definition. `void buildList() {...` IAC I prefer `void buildList(void) { ...`

Comment: @chux: Follow the white rabbit and see what a _function declarator_ is (6.7.6.3, also 6.7.6.3p12). Remember a definition is always also a declaration. And: what you mean is a prototype, where `void f(void);` is very different from `void f();` == `void f(int);`.

Comment: @Olaf: In section 6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes), it says: _¶14 An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters. The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied._ For a function definition, as in the question, omitting the `void` is permitted and valid and defines that the function takes no parameters. I won't adjudicate on whether it constitutes a prototype for it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I did not say it is invalid. It is just an obsolescence features, according to 6.11.6p1. That section applies to _function declarators_ in general, which includes the declarator for a _function definition. See may comments above.

Comment: That's not to say I think it is a good idea to omit the `(void)` — I don't think it is a good idea and I don't omit it in my own code.  But I'm counselling caution on being too dogmatic about it.  Note that the empty brackets (parentheses) in a function declaration, as opposed to function definition, is always a bad idea — either specify `(void)` to indicate no arguments or specify the actual argument list correctly.  In a declaration, the empty brackets are a hangover from the pre-standard C days.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: A _function definition_ **always** is also a _function declaration_. I just wrote a comment that it is deprecated, which is definitively true. I didn't start the fire ... From the view of consistency, an empty paramter list is problematic, because they have different meaning for prototype and definition. That's why I enforce the full variant in my projects' coding styles, too.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things here.

You probably want to hold the pointer to the ErrorCheck structure in something other than a local variable which will disappear once the buildList function returns. You might return it from the function to the caller and store it somewhere more persistent (global variable or local variable in 'main'). You don't need to allocate the list variable right away but it would be a good idea to initialize it to NULL. Then use another function to add nodes by allocating the 'next' pointer and setting its contents (name, grade and NULL).

You can later step through the chain of nodes to list them or free them one by one when you are done. Freeing the list might be a little tricky for a new c coder; but that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

You need two malloc's. malloc only allocate memory for members of a structure. In your example, the first malloc allocates memory for two 8-byte pointers and an integer. A Node structure is not allocated automatically.

Comment: "malloc only allocate memory for members of a structure." - No. It allocates a block of memory for an object of the `struct` type, not just the members (how would that work?). And there is no indicator the pointers have 8 bytes. That is irrelevant at that level. Don't mix implementation details unnecssarily.